# Добавить файлы архива в удаленный репозиторий

Tags: git

По неким причинам разработчик не может залить изменения в удаленный репозиторий, мне прислали архив с проектом в котором содержаться его изменения. В репозитории уже есть коммиты сверху, по сравнению с той версией проекта, которая была у него. Как правильно сравнить версии, понять что он добавил и перенести в проект?

Comment: Раз ты знаешь от какой ревизии он делал изменения, то создать ветку от той ревизии, положить в неё его изменения и замержить.

Comment: А если он может доставать изменения, но не может их пушить, то изучите команды `git format-patch`/`git apply`.

Comment: Главное - чтобы он прислал архив вместе с папкой `.git`, тогда для просмотра его изменений можно выполнить `git log`, а затем подтянуть новые коммиты из репозитория, сделать rebase и push